# java.lang.ClassCastException: Model.ProfessionalUser cannot be cast to Model.User

Tags: java, classcastexception

I am having issues with my code regarding these classes. In the if statement for the login controller, where it authenticates the user (both professionaluser and user getting the same error in their retrospective if statements) I am getting this exception: "java.lang.RuntimeException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException,and java.lang.ClassCastException. I placed the code output below with more details. Thank you for any help provided.

ControllerLogin.java:

```
package Controller;

import Model.ProfessionalUserData;
import Model.User;
import Model.UserData;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ControllerLogin implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;
    @FXML
    private Button signupButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField usernameField;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordField;

    //######################LOGIN SCREEN###########################

    @FXML
    private void setToSignUpScreen(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Controller.loadScreen("SignUpScreen.fxml", event);
    }

    @FXML
    private void authenticate(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Model.UserData userData = new UserData();
        Model.ProfessionalUserData professionalUserData = new ProfessionalUserData();
        System.out.println("Authenticating...");
        if (!userData.searchUsersData(usernameField.getText()).getUsername().isEmpty() && userData.searchUsersData(usernameField.getText()).getUsername().equals(usernameField.getText()) && userData.searchUsersData(usernameField.getText()).getPassword().equals(passwordField.getText())){
            //Checks if user is blank, then checks if username and password match to database
            System.out.println("Loading Regular User Screen");
            Controller.loadScreen("MainScreenUser.fxml", event);
            ControllerMainEmpty.user = userData.searchUsersData(usernameField.getText());

        } else if (!professionalUserData.searchUsersData(usernameField.getText()).getUsername().isEmpty() && professionalUserData.searchUsersData(usernameField.getText()).getUsername().equals(usernameField.getText()) && professionalUserData.searchUsersData(usernameField.getText()).getPassword().equals(passwordField.getText())) {
            System.out.println("Loading Professional User Screen");
            Controller.loadScreen("MainScreenProfUser.fxml", event);
            ControllerMainEmpty.profUser = professionalUserData.searchUsersData(usernameField.getText());
            ControllerMainEmpty.user = new User();
            }
         else {
            usernameField.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            passwordField.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

ProfessionalUserData.java:

```
    package Model;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProfessionalUserData implements Serializable {
    private static ArrayList<ProfessionalUser> professionalUserData = new ArrayList<>();
    /**
     * @return the professionalUserData
     */
    public static ArrayList<ProfessionalUser> getProfessionalUserData() {
        return professionalUserData;
    }

    /**
     * @param aUsersData the professionalUserData to set
     */
    public static void setProfessionalUserData(ArrayList<ProfessionalUser> aUsersData) {
        professionalUserData = aUsersData;
    }

    String usersDataFileName = "ProfessionalUsersData.ser";

    public ProfessionalUserData() {

        this.read();
        if(professionalUserData.isEmpty()|| professionalUserData == null){
//        this.createTestUsersData();
            this.write();
            this.read();
        }
    }

    private void createTestUsersData() {
        for(int i = 0; i <20; i++){
            getProfessionalUserData().add(new ProfessionalUser("firstName" + i, "lastName" + i, "username" + i, "password" + i));
        }
    }

    public void read(){
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(usersDataFileName);

            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            setProfessionalUserData((ArrayList<ProfessionalUser>) ois.readObject());
            ois.close();
            if(!professionalUserData.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("There's users");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void write(){
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(usersDataFileName);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(getProfessionalUserData());
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ProfessionalUser searchUsersData(String username){
        for(int i = 0; i < getProfessionalUserData().size(); i++){
            if (getProfessionalUserData().get(i).getUsername().equals(username)){
                return getProfessionalUserData().get(i);
            }

        }
        return new ProfessionalUser();
    }

    public void writeUser(String username, ProfessionalUser professionalUser){
        for(int i = 0; i < getProfessionalUserData().size(); i++){
            if (getProfessionalUserData().get(i).getUsername().equals(username)){
                getProfessionalUserData().get(i).setProfessionalUser(professionalUser);
            }

        }
        write();
    }

    public void addUser(ProfessionalUser professionalUser){
        getProfessionalUserData().add(professionalUser);
        write();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getProfessionalUserDataNames() {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ProfessionalUser i : getProfessionalUserData()) {
            names.add(i.getFirstName() + " " + i.getLastName());
        }
        return names;
    }

    public ProfessionalUser getProfessionalUser(int index) {
        return getProfessionalUserData().get(index);
    }


}
```

And finally, UserData.java:

```
package Model;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserData implements Serializable {

    /**
     * @return the usersData
     */
    public static ArrayList<User> getUsersData() {
        return usersData;
    }

    /**
     * @param aUsersData the usersData to set
     */
    public static void setUsersData(ArrayList<User> aUsersData) {
        usersData = aUsersData;
    }
    private static ArrayList<User> usersData = new ArrayList<>();
    String usersDataFileName = "UsersData.ser";

    public UserData() {

        this.read();
        if(usersData.isEmpty()|| usersData == null){
//        this.createTestUsersData();
            this.write();
            this.read();
        }
    }

    private void createTestUsersData() {
        for(int i = 0; i <20; i++){
            getUsersData().add(new User("firstName" + i, "lastName" + i, "username" + i, "password" + i, "phoneNumber" + i));
        }
    }

    public void read(){
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(usersDataFileName);

            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            setUsersData((ArrayList<User>) ois.readObject());
            ois.close();
            if(!usersData.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("There's users");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void write(){
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(usersDataFileName);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(getUsersData());
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public User searchUsersData(String username){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < getUsersData().size();i++){
            if (getUsersData().get(i).getUsername().equals(username)){
                return getUsersData().get(i);
            }

        }
        return new User();
    }

    public void writeUser(String username, User user){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < getUsersData().size();i++){
            if (getUsersData().get(i).getUsername().equals(username)){
                getUsersData().get(i).setUser(user);
            }

        }
        write();
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        getUsersData().add(user);
        write();
    }

}
```

Code Output with exception:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=58263:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\ABIST412Fa19T\out\production\ABIST412Fa19Team2;C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\ABIST412Fa19T\libs\jcalendar_1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\ABIST412Fa19T\libs\LGoodDatePicker-10.4.1.jar Controller.Main
There's users
There's users
Authenticating...
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Model.ProfessionalUser cannot be cast to Model.User
    at Model.UserData.searchUsersData(UserData.java:80)
    at Controller.ControllerLogin.authenticate(ControllerLogin.java:45)
    ... 58 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

MainScreenProfUser.FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
      prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="Controller.ControllerMainScreenProfUser">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="seeRequests" layoutX="235.0" layoutY="159.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="See Open Requests" />
      <Button fx:id="cancelAppointments" layoutX="403.0" layoutY="159.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setNotSupportedYet" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Cancel Appointments" />
      <Button fx:id="editProfile" layoutX="132.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setNotSupportedYet" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Edit Profile" />
      <Button fx:id="changePassword" layoutX="338.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setChangePasswordScreen" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Change Password" />
      <Text layoutX="260.0" layoutY="50.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Welcome ">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <Button fx:id="changeAvailability" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="159.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="130.0" text="Change Availability" />
      <Text layoutX="260.0" layoutY="105.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Main Menu">
         <font>
            <Font size="16.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
       <Button fx:id="signOutButton" layoutX="502.0" layoutY="18.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#setToSignedOut"
               text="Sign Out"/>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

NEW ERROR:

```
Dec 08, 2019 12:26:45 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 10.0.2
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/C:/Users/User/IdeaProjects/ABIST412Fa19/out/production/ABIST412Fa19Team2/View/MainScreenProfUser.fxml:21

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:618)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:778)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at Controller.Controller.loadScreen(Controller.java:21)
    at Controller.ControllerLogin.authenticate(ControllerLogin.java:52)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: The `getUsername()` method is not defined for `User`, but is defined for `ProfessionalUser`; try adding a `getUsername()` method in the `User` class.

Comment: oops, I had the professionalUser class in there, meant to post the professionalUserData. userData holds users as objects, both professionalUser and user classes have a getUserName().

Comment: Did you intend to have `ProfessionalUser extends User`? Because otherwise, you cannot cast an instance of ProfessionalUser to User.

Comment: Removing: 
ControllerMainEmpty.user = new User(); 

fixed this but now I am still getting the new error i posted. I don't know why setting a user to new user would cause an exception in that if statement but it did and removing it fixed that particular cast exception.

Comment: added MainScreenProfUser.FXML code

Comment: managed to fix it... issue was in the fxml file, but if anyone can explain to me why removing ControllerMainEmpty.user = new User(); fixed the cast exception that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. One exception was fixed by removing "ControllerMainEmpty.user = new User();" under the professional user login check if statement... I do not know why because ControllerMainEmpty.user IS an user.

Second fix was by going into the FXML provided above and fixing an onaction command, the one with empty quotes.